# Is there a name for the red circle and slash in a No Smoking sign?

Tags: signage, iconography

When my daughter asked me and my husband about a No Smoking sign, we explained that it means no cigarettes are allowed.  (We had to explain cigarettes to her too.)

[image]

Unfortunately, she now thinks that the red circle and diagonal line are called a "cigarette", so she'll talk about the cigarette in the No Parking sign:

[image]

Is there a name we can teach her for the red circle and slash?

[image]

Comment: You have no slash in those figures. It’s a backslash, not a slash: the slope is negative not positive. Unicode has it as a combining character: ‭◌ ⃠  U+20E0       COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE BACKSLASH.  So   ⃠   could conceivably be a no crossing sign if you needed it.  That’s a two-codepoint glyph of `\x{1F6B8}\x{20e0}` or `\N{CHILDREN CROSSING}\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING CIRCLE BACKSLASH}`. Note that it is a backslash, not a slash.

Comment: @tchrist For the record, I disagree that “slash” necessarily means a bend dexter or sinister. Unicode may be consistent about it, but Unicode isn't English.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I’m just trying to keep the hobgoblins of foolish inconsistency at bay.

Comment: @tchrist The hobgoblins of foolish inconsistency make the world what it is. Without foolish inconsistency there could be no experimentation.  That said:  I LOVE THAT PHRASE!!!!!!!

Comment: @DavidM: The full quote is: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines." -- Ralph Waldo Emerson

Comment: @tchrist, interesting point.  I'm a computer scientist and know well the difference between a slash and backslash but didn't register it in this context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[No symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol).

> The **no symbol (also prohibition sign, no sign, circle-backslash symbol, nay, or universal no)** is a circle with a diagonal line through it (running from top left to bottom right), surrounding a pictogram used to indicate something is not permitted.

---

**Trivia:** There is also a popular "forward slash" version:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  That's what we had been calling it, but I was hoping there was a "stickier" term.  Maybe we'll just call it the "forbidden" sign (although of course it's not the sign that's forbidden).

Comment: Ah, I hadn't clicked through, not realizing there were other options at the link.  FTR, they are: prohibition sign, no sign, circle-backslash symbol, nay, and universal no.

Comment: Thanks for the Ghostbusters one.  I'm sure my daughter will enjoy decoding it.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to give a "stickier term" which also explained the *meaning* of the red circle symbol with a diagonal slash, I would say:

> That's the ***Do not do*** sign.
>   *Do not smoke*; *do not park here*; *do not use a mobile here*<sup>[1](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_T2wj8yRqk2g/TOlw61Ghr_I/AAAAAAAAADY/RFMtdjoq6Hg/s1600/Do+not+use+mobile+phone.jpg)</sup>; *do not take photos* <sup>[2](http://images.sodahead.com/polls/003983616/415284025_no_photo_answer_4_xlarge.jpeg)</sup> etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about the "verboten" symbol?

[image]

Comment: That isn't English. It gets used in English, but it ain't English.

Comment: @David M: According to Collins, _verboten_ is as English as _pyjamas_ say nowadays.

Comment: If you saw that sign without text, and were asked what it means, wouldn't you say _No smoking_ rather than _Smoking verboten_?

Comment: If I was talking to my kid, I'd just as likely say "das ist verboten!", whilst spitting on him.